# "This box of matches is empty"

Tags: grammaticality, meaning-in-context, word-choice

There are several Japanese books teaching Japanese students how to write in English. I found this example in [『英作文参考書の誤りを正す』](http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E8%8B%B1%E4%BD%9C%E6%96%87%E5%8F%82%E8%80%83%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%AE%E8%AA%A4%E3%82%8A%E3%82%92%E6%AD%A3%E3%81%99-%E6%B2%B3%E4%B8%8A-%E9%81%93%E7%94%9F/dp/4469241512) (*Correcting Errors in English Composition Manuals*) by Michio Kawakami and J.D. Monkman.

The authors of this book claim that this sentence is incorrect:

> This box of matches is empty.

They note that a “box of matches” is a box containing matches (and not a box made out of matches), hence the sentence should instead be:

> This **matchbox** is empty.

Likewise, an “empty bottle of beer” should instead be an “empty beer bottle.”

Is this actually an error that I should avoid in writing English? If so, is it a grammatical error or something else?

Comment: They're both fine, grammatically. I'm more curious about the exact phrase the author used in the book. And also, the context.

Comment: @DamkerngT. He said: A box of matches is a box containing matches, hence the sentence should be:
"This matchbox is empty" because a matchbox can be empty.
Likewise a bottle of beer is a bottle containing beer. If you drink the beer and empty it,
it is a beer bottle but no longer a bottle of beer.

Comment: Here is what I believe. I believe that both are possible, but "(a) box of matches" can be ambiguous, and as a result, it is safer for students to avoid. Let's have a look at real usages in Google Ngram: [empby box of matches vs. empty matchbox(es)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=empty+box+of+matches%2Cempty+matchboxes%2Cempty+matchbox&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=1&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cempty%20box%20of%20matches%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cempty%20matchboxes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cempty%20matchbox%3B%2Cc0). ...

Comment: ... which led me to this example: "[You Gotta Have a Gimmick: an empty box of matches, a penny, and a piece of felt](http://books.google.co.th/books?id=SHt4GDgoa0kC&pg=PA79)". Here is another result from Google Ngram: [this box of matches,this matchbox](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=this+box+of+matches%2Cthis+matchbox&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthis%20box%20of%20matches%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthis%20matchbox%3B%2Cc0), ...

Comment: ... which led me to "[For example we found this box of matches back there, any reason we'd find your fingerprints on it?](http://books.google.com/books?id=JuMzKpFu93IC&pg=PA165)".

Comment: @DamkerngT. Could you tell me what those sources are?
Are they writings by native English speakers?

Comment: I would believe that Walter Brown Gibson, Nathan J. Gordon, and William L. Fleisher are native English speakers.

Comment: Did the original author actually write that the sentence is **grammatically** incorrect? Or did he simply state that there are better ways to write it? **Grammatical** means something more specific.

Comment: @BraddSzonye He said "box of matches" *should* be replaced by "matchbox" in his book called "Correcting errors of books on how to write in English" and the sentence was borrowed from one of those books. It is clear that he thinks it is incorrect.

Comment: That doesn't actually imply that the sentence is incorrect, but merely that it can be improved. And it is a very different thing from saying that it is *grammatically* incorrect.

Comment: @BraddSzonye [*That doesn't actually imply that the sentence is incorrect, but merely that it can be improved.*] Why do you think so? He is correcting *errors*.

Comment: That sort of “error” is very different from a grammatical error – it's usually called a style error, and it isn't universally regarded as incorrect. It's more of a guideline. (The same is true to some extent of grammatical errors, but people are generally more sensitive to strange grammar than they are to strange style.)

Comment: @BraddSzonye What is your definition of "grammar"?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammar – in particular note the discussion “Use of the term.” I use *grammar* in the sense that linguists do, whereas your question uses in this sense: “Grammar is often a generic way of referring to any aspect of English that people object to.” In the context of learning English, and especially at [english.se], it's a good idea to use the linguist's definition. (For more information, I recommend asking about this in chat here or at ELU. Or posting a question specifically about it – but check for duplicates first.)

Comment: @MakotoKato Is it remotely possible that the author meant this as a joke or even as a _philosophical_ side-note?

Comment: @helix I don't think so. The sentence is from one of those books on how to write in English and the author is correcting errors of those books.

Comment: @BraddSzonye 英作文参考書 means books teaching English composition.
It is plural in the context of the book title.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on my title translation! I'm doing the best I can with my limited knowledge of Japanese and Google Translate to figure out an idiomatic English equivalent, so I may be missing some subtleties. This is the correct book though, yes?

Comment: @BraddSzonye [*“English Composition Reference Series: Correcting Errors”*]
This is not correct.
The book is correcting errors of textbooks teaching how to write in English.
I have no idea why you don't believe me.

Comment: My apologies! I don't understand Japanese grammar well enough to figure out how 英作文参考書 fit in, so I didn't realize what you were trying to tell me. Would “Correcting Errors in English Composition Manuals” be a better translation?

Comment: In any case, I hope that you found my edit and my answer helpful, and I apologize for any offense or confusion that I caused in our discussion yesterday.

Comment: @BraddSzonye No problem. Thanks for your edit.
英作文参考書 is a book which teaches how to compose English sentences.
If you call them "English Composition Manuals", I think it's OK.

Answer (score 9):

As a native speaker, I would **not** regard *empty box of matches, empty bottle of beer, empty glass of water*, or *empty tin of sardines* to be "wrong". Anyone arguing that I should say instead *empty matchbox, empty beer bottle, empty water glass*, and *empty sardine tin* probably wouldn't get in too many more discussions with me, as I'd likely regard them as a *pompous [bag of wind](https://www.wordnik.com/words/windbag)*.

To echo what @Bradd Szonye mentioned in the comments, there's a difference between "grammatically wrong" and "preferred in formal writing." An *empty beer bottle* may be a better way of saying it, but "grammatically wrong" is overstated.

There are times when we should be very careful in our wording, when it behooves us to be very fussy about such details (for example, when we are writing a resume to compete against 50 or 60 other people for a coveted job, or writing an academic paper that will be read with scrutiny by our peers). Other situations don't require such careful attention to linguistic quirks. I would say that *empty box of matches* falls squarely under the umbrella of *good enough for everyday conversation*.

Comment: Excellent answer, J.R. You might want to answer [the other version of this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159116/this-box-of-matches-is-empty) at [english.se] if you think it would be helpful there too. I edited that copy of the question to reflect some of the comments here, and to link to the reference work that Makato Kato appears to be using.

Comment: I'm sending the book author the following suggestion: ***When referring to a box in which it's unknown how many matches are in it, one must say, "hand me that box of matches or that matchbox, depending on what it really is."***

Comment: I'd like to point out that a good academic book should have a proper balance of subject material.  Even if the author was correct, there are so many more important English language issues that this particular detail seems trivial (congratulations - follow this book and you can talk to smokers and drinkers without them laughing at you for your obvious failure to apply subtle language logic).  I wonder if the author has  a cognitive bias, such as a (hypothetical) bias of Japanese in which this type of distinction would be important.

Comment: @CoolHand - Good analysis. Had the book been entitled _Subtle Slip-Ups in the English Language (and How to Avoid Them)_, a lot of folks here might have marveled at the authors' insight. Instead, it was presented to us as "incorrect," as though a non-native speaker would be jeered after saying something stupid like "this box of matches is empty" – which isn't the case at all. Unless someone fluent in both languages has read the book, it'll be hard to tell if these are truly presented as _errors_, or mere _novelties_. These oddities can be fun to think about so long as we don't get too pedantic.

Answer (score 4):

When you say **a box of matches** you mean a matchbox which contains matches.

Let's say I'll bring a bottle of milk for you. What do you expect? An empty bottle?

By and large, a box of matches means what I have said.

But **the box of matches** lays more stress on the box itself. It may be empty or not.

Comment: May I ask if you are a native English speaker?

Comment: Nope, does it matter? I think I am right about it.

Comment: I disagree. A box of matches could mean *a box used for the purpose of storing matches*. It may or may not be empty.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But I think _a matchbox_ is better. It's unambiguous. Again, context is everything.

Answer (score 3):

Most native English speakers would find nothing strange about an “empty box of matches” or an “empty bottle of beer.” They would readily interpret these phrases as a “box [for] matches” or perhaps a “bottle [previously full] of beer.”

If you pointed out that “empty matchbox” or “empty beer bottle” is preferable, a fluent English speaker might agree, or might just shrug and wonder what the big deal is about. Diction choices like this are a matter of **style,** and poor choices are **style errors.** Most rules of style are subjective, so what looks like a style error to one writer (like the authors of your reference book) might be perfectly acceptable to another. One of the functions of a **[style guide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Style_guide)** is to recommend specific choices for diction, spelling, punctuation, formatting, *etc.* to maintain a consistent style in publications.

Note that this construction is not a [grammatical error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammar#Use_of_the_term), at least not as the term is used by linguists. Jeremy Butterfield aptly notes that “Grammar is often a generic way of referring to any aspect of English that people object to.” While linguists and other serious language enthusiasts use *grammar* to mean a variety of things, it generally relates to the structure of language rather than its meaning. Thus, phrases like “this serious kerfuffle of parsnips” are **grammatical** even though they might not make sense at all, because there's nothing wrong with the structure of the phrase. The same is true for “empty box of matches.”

All that said, many native speakers **would** object if you changed the example slightly:

> This bottle of beer is full of milk.

We call this kind of style error a [garden path sentence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_path_sentence) because readers are lured down one path (thinking that the bottle is full of beer) and then suddenly surprised by what they find at the end of the sentence (that it's actually full of milk). A garden path sentence forces the reader to suddenly re-interpret the sentence to make sense of it, often requiring a completely different parse of the grammar. For example:

> Time flies like an arrow; fruit flies like a banana.

---

<sup>Note: This is a copy of [the answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/159856/42788) I posted at [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/).</sup>

Comment: **This bottle of beer is full of milk.**  This phrasing is also fun to use for humor-wordplay when such a situation actually occurs.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you've pulled this out of context, you have yourself a book of corrections that needs correcting. I believe that the author is just trying to remove 'needless words'. A 'box of matches' is indeed a 'matchbox'. To say 'matchbox' is more common, more natural, a better demonstration of linguistic skill etc, but a 'box of matches' is still correct.

...This question is hardly off-topic. The people who make such declarations are a little too fine with their combing sometimes.

Comment: The OP states that he's translating advice from a Japanese book, and I suspect that he doesn't realize that *grammatical* has a specific technical meaning in this context.